# ¿Cómo hacer que en mi array no se estén repitiendo los valores?

Tags: c++

hola tengo una duda y es sobre un problema que tengo con los array de este ejercicio y es que se repite en varias casillas del array y lo que quería hacer es como no hacer que se repitan y no llene dicho espacio del array

digamos en este programa hara la solicitud de 2 valores enteros que hay que ingresar para nuestro ejemplo utilizaremos 6 y 2 a la hora de ingresar esos 2 valores hara llamar al documento divisores.h para que haga el procedimiento

'archivo cpp'

```
#include <iostream>
#include"divisores.h"
using namespace std;
int a, b, x[99], y[99];
int main()
{
    cout<<"ingrese un valor de: "<<endl;
    cout<<"A: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"B: ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<endl;
    
    divisores(x, y, a, b);
    
    cout<<"datos de A: ";
    for(int i=1; i<=a ;i++){
        cout<<x[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    
    cout<<"datos de B: ";
    for(int i=1; i<=b ;i++){
        cout<<y[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

'archivo .h'
de este archivo hara el llamado la cual me reenviara los datos que me dice que me dara al ingresar los valores

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


 void divisores(int x[], int y[], int a, int b){
int dato1, dato2;

if(a<0){
     a=a*-1;
}

if(b<0){
    b=b*-1;
}


    for(int j=1; j<=a; j=j+1){
         if(a>=0 && a%j==0){
             dato1=j;
            }
            x[j]=dato1;
        }
        

     for(int j=1; j<=b; j=j+1){
         if(b>=0 && b%j==0){
             dato2=j;
            }
           y[j]=dato2;
        }

    

}
```

y la cual quiero que me salgan de esta manera
`x[0]=1, x[1]=2, x[1]=3 y x[3]=6 por otro y[0]=1, y[1]=2`

pero me aparece repetidas y tomando casillas demás

`x[0]=1, x[1]=2, x[2]=3, x[3]=3, x[4]=3, x[5]=6`

`y[0]=1, y[1]=2`

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y reemplaza las imágenes por código en modo texto. El código de las imágenes no se puede copiar y, si la imagen deja de estar disponible en el futuro, la pregunta no será de utilidad para nadie

Comment: Deberías explicar de donde salen esos calores, porque entrando 6,2. obtienes una salida de 1,2,3,6 y 1,2.

Comment: gracias por la sugerencia y ya esta hecho

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu código, entiendo que pretendes almacenar en un array, los distintos divisores del valor indicado.
Por ejemplo, si introduces 6, quieres almacenar el 1,2,3 y 6. 
En ese caso, el problema de tu código, es que al salir del condicional, siempre introduces el valor de la variable `dato1` en el array, así que, cuando los valores a comprobar sean el 4 y 5, que no son divisores, introduce el último divisor obtenido, el 3, y por eso repite el 3 tres veces.
Así que solo deberías introducir el valor en caso que sea divisor, o sea, dentro del condicional. Un ejemplo podría ser este:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x[99];
    int i=0;
    int j;
    int a=6;
    for(j=1; j<=a; j++){
        if(a>=0 && a%j==0){
            x[i++]=j;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout<<a<<" tiene "<<i<<" divisores:\n";
    for (j=0 ; j<i; j++) {
     std::cout<<x[j]<<" ";   
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por qué el código es JS?

Comment: Porque su problema no tiene nada que ver con el lenguaje, si no con la mecánica, y con un snipet se puede ver el resultado del ejemplo.
Además, esta pregunta se ha editado múltiples veces, la pregunta original solo tenia dos bucles.

Comment: `uint` no es un tipo de C++. Puedes ver que [el compilador da error](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/vzQzr0QhT8FWwcCaiwvEzk3MzNPQrFao/f8fAA). Si existen [enteros de tamaño fijo](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) desde C++11. Por ejemplo `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t`, `uint8_t`, ...

Comment: He usado un compilador online y no se ha quejado, pero vale.